# How to save And delete document after CLOSE event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that stores word documents in a database, and they are repeatedly opened, closed by the user and then saved back to the database.
when opening I place them on a temp folder.
but when closed, I want to save is back to the database and then delete it directly.

I tried this:

```
...

((DocumentEvents_Event)document).Close += DocumentClose;

...

delegate void MethodDelegate();

private void DocumentClose()
{
     new MethodDelegate(deleteLater)();
}

void deleteLater()
{
     //document.Close();
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     File.Delete(this.tempDocFilePath);
}
```

but this don't work, and I get an error message telling me the file is already opened.
and when I uncomment "document.Close();" the next two lines are not excuted

any Ideas ?

Comment: How are you opening the document?

Comment: The document has to be closed so you can delete the file.  Find out why it is crashing on the Close() call, remove any try/catch statements.

Comment: @Mark Avenius: first I created an application object:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Then used "app.Documents.Open()" method

Comment: @Hans Passant: the document is not being closed and disposed (and the file released) before the Close event is fully excuted

Answer (score 1):

This code is possibly subject to a race condition. NEVER trust a Sleep-solution. Wait for a specific event or poll and then take action.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it !

here's my code snippent:

```
private static Thread oThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(delete));

...

((DocumentEvents_Event)document).Close += DocumentClose;

...


private static void DocumentClose()
{
      oThread.Start(path);
}

static void delete(object path)
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete((string)path);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        delete(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use recursion when it's not necessary, you could trigger a StackOverflow exception. Use a while loop.