# C# Word Interop. ((DocumentEvents_Event)document).Close is not firing when document is closed

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

as the title says: `((DocumentEvents_Event)document).Close` is not firing when closing the word document.

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(pathToDocument);

...

document.Activate();
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.Activate();

((DocumentEvents_Event)document).Close += OnDocumentClosed;

...

private void OnDocumentClosed()
{
...
}
```

I close the word document by closing Word itself. It works 3 out of 5 times i try and `OnDocumentClosed()` is called. Does anyone know what i did wrong? I need it to work 5 out of 5 times. I use **Word 2016**.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

parzi

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but it seems you might get a solution from similar needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832558/how-to-save-and-delete-document-after-close-event

Comment: @SanketTarunShah i am trying to get the closing event fired. Thanks for the link, but its a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to be sure the source object is alive. For implementing that you need to declare the source object at the global scope, so it is not swiped by the garbage collector.

```
// declare at the class level
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(pathToDocument);

// somewhere in the code
document.Activate();
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.Activate();
((DocumentEvents_Event)document).Close += OnDocumentClosed;

// event handler
private void OnDocumentClosed()
{
...
}
```

Comment: I think thats it! Thanks a lot!